# Will Office 365 (Admin center or Powershell) tell me if a user's password is expired?

Tags: powershell, passwords, office365

I feel like this question has to have been asked before, but I've spent way too much time searching for it here and elsewhere.

I'm looking for something to tell me that a user's password has expired. When I search for this, I get a ton of sites telling me how to set a user's password to never expire or how to set the password policy. I just want to be able to look up a user in the Admin Center or using PowerShell to see if the password is expired.

I user this cmdlet as a workaround for the moment, but it would be so much easier if I could have it tell me "Password Expired: Yes" or something like that.

```
Get-MsolUser -SearchString (Read-Host `n Whose info?) | select DisplayName, LastPasswordChangeTimeStamp, @{Name=”PasswordAge (in days.time)”;Expression={(Get-Date)-$_.LastPasswordChangeTimeStamp}}, PasswordNeverExpires | fl
```

Thanks!

**04-Aug-16 Edit based on Junaid's suggested answer below:**

I've changed the script to allow for searching, for vertical spacing, and for the accounts where PasswordNeverExpires = TRUE. I hope it's helpful.

```
$valid = Get-MsolPasswordPolicy -DomainName domain.com | select ValidityPeriod -ExpandProperty ValidityPeriod

Get-MsolUser -SearchString (Read-Host `n Whose info?) | Select DisplayName, LastPasswordChangeTimeStamp, PasswordNeverExpires | foreach{ 
 $user = $_.DisplayName
 $exp = $_.LastPasswordChangeTimeStamp.addDays($valid)
 If ($_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $TRUE){
 $exp = "Never"
 }
 Write-Output "$user's Password Expiration: $exp"
}
Write-Output `n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this. First get the domain's password policy and save the ValidityPeriod to a variable. Then get all users and their last password change time stamp, add the validity period to it and there you have it, the date when the password will expire.

```
 $valid = Get-MsolPasswordPolicy -DomainName yourdomain.com | select ValidityPeriod -ExpandProperty ValidityPeriod
```

Now we have the validity period in $valid variable.

```
 Get-MsolUser -All | Select UserPrincipalName, LastPasswordChangeTimeStamp | foreach{ 
 $user = $_.UserPrincipalName
 $exp = $_.LastPasswordChangeTimeStamp.addDays($valid)
 Write-Output "$user's password expires on $exp"
}
```

I ran this in a powershell session with Msol service connected. So i hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, Junaid. This certainly does what I want, and I'll definitely be using it. I was just hoping that there was already this functionality built into the Admin Center or as a property of Get-MsolUser, something like PasswordExpired with a TRUE or FALSE value.